# ColdFusion XmlSearch(): XPath with namespaces

Tags: xml, soap, xpath, coldfusion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/><soapenv:Body><v9:ProcessShipmentReply xmlns:v9="http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v9"><v9:HighestSeverity xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">SUCCESS</v9:HighestSeverity><v9:Notifications xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><v9:Severity>SUCCESS</v9:Severity><v9:Source>ship</v9:Source><v9:Code>0000</v9:Code><v9:Message>Success</v9:Message><v9:LocalizedMessage>Success</v9:LocalizedMessage></v9:Notifications><v9:Version>
                            <v9:ServiceId>ship</v9:ServiceId>
                            <v9:Major>9</v9:Major>

                            <v9:Intermediate>0</v9:Intermediate>
                            <v9:Minor>0</v9:Minor>
                         </v9:Version><v9:CompletedShipmentDetail><v9:UsDomestic xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</v9:UsDomestic><v9:CarrierCode xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">FDXE</v9:CarrierCode><v9:ServiceTypeDescription xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">INTL PRIORITY</v9:ServiceTypeDescription><v9:PackagingDescription xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">YOUR_PACKAGING</v9:PackagingDescription><v9:RoutingDetail xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><v9:UrsaPrefixCode>9F</v9:UrsaPrefixCode><v9:UrsaSuffixCode>QNJA </v9:UrsaSuffixCode><v9:OriginLocationId>QVAA </v9:OriginLocationId><v9:OriginServiceArea>AM</v9:OriginServiceArea><v9:DestinationLocationId>QNJA </v9:DestinationLocationId><v9:DestinationServiceArea>PM</v9:DestinationServiceArea><v9:DestinationLocationStateOrProvinceCode>  </v9:DestinationLocationStateOrProvinceCode><v9:AstraPlannedServiceLevel>PM</v9:AstraPlannedServiceLevel><v9:AstraDescription>INTL PRIORITY</v9:AstraDescription><v9:PostalCode>74940</v9:PostalCode><v9:StateOrProvinceCode>  </v9:StateOrProvinceCode><v9:CountryCode>FR</v9:CountryCode><v9:AirportId>CDG</v9:AirportId></v9:RoutingDetail><v9:ShipmentRating xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><v9:ActualRateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT_SHIPMENT</v9:ActualRateType><v9:ShipmentRateDetails><v9:RateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT_SHIPMENT</v9:RateType><v9:RateScale>0000000</v9:RateScale><v9:RateZone>IT001O</v9:RateZone><v9:PricingCode>ACTUAL</v9:PricingCode><v9:RatedWeightMethod>ACTUAL</v9:RatedWeightMethod><v9:CurrencyExchangeRate><v9:FromCurrency>EUR</v9:FromCurrency><v9:IntoCurrency>USD</v9:IntoCurrency><v9:Rate>1.37</v9:Rate></v9:CurrencyExchangeRate><v9:DimDivisor>0</v9:DimDivisor><v9:FuelSurchargePercent>12.5</v9:FuelSurchargePercent><v9:TotalBillingWeight><v9:Units>KG</v9:Units><v9:Value>6.0</v9:Value></v9:TotalBillingWeight><v9:TotalBaseCharge><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>142.27</v9:Amount></v9:TotalBaseCharge><v9:TotalFreightDiscounts><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>0.0</v9:Amount></v9:TotalFreightDiscounts><v9:TotalNetFreight><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>142.27</v9:Amount></v9:TotalNetFreight><v9:TotalSurcharges><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>17.78</v9:Amount></v9:TotalSurcharges><v9:TotalNetFedExCharge><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>160.05</v9:Amount></v9:TotalNetFedExCharge><v9:TotalTaxes><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>0.0</v9:Amount></v9:TotalTaxes><v9:TotalNetCharge><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>160.05</v9:Amount></v9:TotalNetCharge><v9:TotalRebates><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>0.0</v9:Amount></v9:TotalRebates><v9:Surcharges><v9:SurchargeType>FUEL</v9:SurchargeType><v9:Description>Fuel</v9:Description><v9:Amount><v9:Currency>USD</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>17.78</v9:Amount></v9:Amount></v9:Surcharges></v9:ShipmentRateDetails><v9:ShipmentRateDetails><v9:RateType>RATED_ACCOUNT_SHIPMENT</v9:RateType><v9:RateScale>0000000</v9:RateScale><v9:RateZone>IT001O</v9:RateZone><v9:PricingCode>ACTUAL</v9:PricingCode><v9:RatedWeightMethod>ACTUAL</v9:RatedWeightMethod><v9:CurrencyExchangeRate><v9:FromCurrency>EUR</v9:FromCurrency><v9:IntoCurrency>EUR</v9:IntoCurrency><v9:Rate>1.0</v9:Rate></v9:CurrencyExchangeRate><v9:DimDivisor>0</v9:DimDivisor><v9:FuelSurchargePercent>12.5</v9:FuelSurchargePercent><v9:TotalBillingWeight><v9:Units>KG</v9:Units><v9:Value>6.0</v9:Value></v9:TotalBillingWeight><v9:TotalBaseCharge><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>103.6</v9:Amount></v9:TotalBaseCharge><v9:TotalFreightDiscounts><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>0.0</v9:Amount></v9:TotalFreightDiscounts><v9:TotalNetFreight><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>103.6</v9:Amount></v9:TotalNetFreight><v9:TotalSurcharges><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>12.95</v9:Amount></v9:TotalSurcharges><v9:TotalNetFedExCharge><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>116.55</v9:Amount></v9:TotalNetFedExCharge><v9:TotalTaxes><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>0.0</v9:Amount></v9:TotalTaxes><v9:TotalNetCharge><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>116.55</v9:Amount></v9:TotalNetCharge><v9:TotalRebates><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>0.0</v9:Amount></v9:TotalRebates><v9:Surcharges><v9:SurchargeType>FUEL</v9:SurchargeType><v9:Description>Fuel</v9:Description><v9:Amount><v9:Currency>EUR</v9:Currency><v9:Amount>12.95</v9:Amount></v9:Amount></v9:Surcharges></v9:ShipmentRateDetails></v9:ShipmentRating><v9:IneligibleForMoneyBackGuarantee xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">false</v9:IneligibleForMoneyBackGuarantee><v9:CompletedPackageDetails xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><v9:SequenceNumber>1</v9:SequenceNumber><v9:TrackingIds><v9:TrackingIdType>EXPRESS</v9:TrackingIdType><v9:FormId>0430</v9:FormId><v9:TrackingNumber>794794712260</v9:TrackingNumber></v9:TrackingIds><v9:GroupNumber>0</v9:GroupNumber><v9:Barcodes><v9:BinaryBarcodes><v9:Type>COMMON_2D</v9:Type><v9:Value>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</v9:Value></v9:BinaryBarcodes><v9:StringBarcodes><v9:Type>ASTRA</v9:Type><v9:Value>40497199110000047947947122604300</v9:Value></v9:StringBarcodes></v9:Barcodes><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>2</v9:Number><v9:Content>TRK#</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>3</v9:Number><v9:Content>0430</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>5</v9:Number><v9:Content>9F QNJA </v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>7</v9:Number><v9:Content>40497199110000047947947122604300</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>8</v9:Number><v9:Content>512G2/A78E/A278</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>10</v9:Number><v9:Content>7947 9471 2260</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>12</v9:Number><v9:Content>PM</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>13</v9:Number><v9:Content>INTL PRIORITY</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>15</v9:Number><v9:Content>74940</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>16</v9:Number><v9:Content>  -FR</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Number>17</v9:Number><v9:Content>CDG</v9:Content></v9:AstraLabelElements><v9:Label><v9:Type>OUTBOUND_LABEL</v9:Type><v9:ShippingDocumentDisposition>RETURNED</v9:ShippingDocumentDisposition><v9:Resolution>200</v9:Resolution><v9:CopiesToPrint>1</v9:CopiesToPrint><v9:Parts><v9:DocumentPartSequenceNumber>1</v9:DocumentPartSequenceNumber><v9:Image>HUGE STUFF!!!</v9:Image></v9:Parts></v9:Label><v9:SignatureOption>SERVICE_DEFAULT</v9:SignatureOption></v9:CompletedPackageDetails></v9:CompletedShipmentDetail></v9:ProcessShipmentReply></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's my SOAP response, from my web service.

I want to **XmlSearch()** to get the `<v9:image>` content.

What's the right XPath? "//v9:image" nor "//image" do not work!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The namespace v9 isn't at the root, so you'll have to modify your syntax slightly to access elements in the v9 section of the XML doc:

```
<cfset results = xmlSearch(myXMLDoc,"//*[local-name()='Image' and namespace-uri()='http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v9']") />
```

Here, you ignore the XML declaration of v9, and explicitly refer to the namespace in the XPath search via `namespace-uri()`, and request the value of the  element with the `local-name()` function.

If v9 was declared at the root (up at the top) of the XML document, the old XPath search syntax you tried using //v9:Image/ would have worked.

Due to the ColdFusion XPath library implementation, there's no way to set the namespace context arbitrarily while you perform your search; you're limited to the namespaces that are declared at the root of the document (and they are poured into the default namespace that XPath can search), thus allowing you to execute a search using namespace aliases such as //v9:Image/. This breaks when, as you get deeper into the XML, new namespaces are introduced.

SOURCE: [Specify xmlns namespaces in an XPath Search](http://www.coldfusionguy.com/ColdFusion/blog/index.cfm/2008/9/26/XMLSearch-Specify-xmlns-namespaces-in-an-xPath-Search)

Comment: An error occured while Searching an XML document.
Prefix must resolve to a namespace:

Comment: quote. " XML root document declaration (including the v9 namespace)..." .. What is that?? O.o

Comment: Go ahead and update the original question with your complete XML document. I have the sneaking suspicion that the v9 namespace isn't declared properly/at the correct position in the doc -- if you don't know what that is, post the ENTIRE xml document, top to bottom.

Comment: however... I can't modify that thing! It's FedEx stuff!!  :-D

Comment: Thank you for posting the complete XML. I've updated/tested my answer for you.

Comment: Is there documentation for this statement somewhere? *"If v9 was declared at the root (up at the top) of the XML document, the old XPath search syntax you tried using //v9:Image/ would have worked."*

Comment: What kind of documentation do you want? A list of XPath functions: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp, the XPath 1.0 RFC: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/, you need to be specific on what you're looking for.

Comment: @ShawnHolmes - Why do you think it matters whether the namespace is declared on the root node? You won't find anything to support that theory in the XPath docs (and in general that's not how namespaces work). If that's necessary, then it's only necessary due to a limitation in ColdFusion's XPath engine, which I'd hope would be documented somewhere.

Comment: @Shawn - You're confused. Those pages do not support your claim that this has anything whatsoever to do with the location of the namespace declaration. In particular, notice that in Java and C# the way you address this issue is to explicitly register the namespace with an arbitrary prefix on the XPath engine. This prefix has nothing to do with the prefix found in the source doc and certainly is not affected by whether or not the original decl is on the root node.

Comment: @ShawnHolmes - See my updated answer for a demonstration of what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: @lwburk Allow me to rephrase: ColdFusion's *XPath library* is not namespace-aware, so you are restricted to XPath functions in order to resolve nested namespaces. In the OP's example, if the v9 namespace attribute was declared at the root level with the remaining namespaces, the original XPath //v9:Image syntax would have sufficed.

Comment: @lwburk, I missed your earlier comment in the thread, re: why does it matter that it is declared at the root node? In CF, those attributes are loaded into the default namespace, which can then be referenced by the typical alias syntax (ie. //v9:Image/), however, any new namespaces introduced in the nesting must be referred to explicitly using Xpath functions.

Comment: @lwburk, I removed the links, to hopefully prevent additional confusion. I originally provided them to show other languages using the same syntax to perform the search, but as you've stated, those examples were used for entirely different reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In most XPath implementations this problem is addressed by registering the namespace URI with an arbitrary prefix in the host language, but I don't see any information related to this in [the `XMLSearch` docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000672.htm#141075) (and Google isn't much help, either).

The following work-around should help in the meantime:

```
//*[local-name()='Image']
```

This selects `image` elements from any (or no) namespace.

Or, more specifically (as shown in @Shawn's answer):

```
//*[local-name()='Image' and namespace-uri()='http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v9']
```

Note, however, that this would be entirely unnecessary, given some way to register the namespace with the XPath engine. For example, consider this complete Java example:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("workbook.xml");
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NamespaceContext ctx = new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        if ("myName".equals(prefix)) {
            return "http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v9";
        } 
        return null;
    }
    public String getPrefix(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    public Iterator getPrefixes(String uri) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
};
xpath.setNamespaceContext(ctx);
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//myName:Image");     

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println("[" + nodes.item(i).getTextContent() + "]");
}
```

Output:

```
[HUGE STUFF!!!]
```

This code associates the prefix `myName` with the namespace URI `http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v9`. Subsequent expressions can refer to nodes in that namespace using the arbitrarily chosen prefix name:

```
//myName:Image
```

One would presume that ColdFusion supports similar functionality, but I was unable to find it in the docs. However, if such functionality does not exist, then this is a *limitation of ColdFusion*. In particular, it has nothing to do with XPath itself or *where* in the source document the namespace declaration appears.