# coldfusion xml parsing

Tags: xml, coldfusion

Given the following XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
   <s:Header>
      <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
         <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2012-08-15T02:11:45.336Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2012-08-15T02:16:45.336Z</u:Expires>
         </u:Timestamp>
      </o:Security>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <GetDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tg.gov.au/services/">
         <GetDetailsResult i:type="Rto" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Codes>
               <OrganisationCode>
                  <StartDate>2003-10-28</StartDate>
                  <Code>0022</Code>
               </OrganisationCode>
            </Codes>
            <Contacts>
               <Contact>
                  <EndDate>2011-10-21</EndDate>
                  <StartDate>2003-10-27</StartDate>
                  <Email>email@address.com</Email>
                  <Fax>08555555</Fax>
                  <FirstName>Steve</FirstName>
                  <JobTitle>Chief Executive Officer</JobTitle>
                  <LastName>Austin</LastName>
                  <OrganisationName>ATEX</OrganisationName>
                  <Phone>13333333</Phone>
                  <PostalAddress>
                     <CountryCode>1101</CountryCode>
                     <Line1>PO Box 555</Line1>
                     <Postcode>5515</Postcode>
                     <StateCode>04</StateCode>
                     <Suburb>PT ADELAIDE</Suburb>
                  </PostalAddress>
                  <RoleCode>1</RoleCode>
                  <Title>Ms</Title>
                  <TypeCode>0</TypeCode>
               </Contact>
            </Contacts>
            <CreatedDate xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
               <a:DateTime>2011-06-09T19:05:11.5427569Z</a:DateTime>
               <a:OffsetMinutes>600</a:OffsetMinutes>
            </CreatedDate>
            <DataManagers>
               <DataManagerAssignment>
                  <StartDate>2003-10-28</StartDate>
                  <Code>03</Code>
               </DataManagerAssignment>
            </DataManagers>
            <Locations>
               <OrganisationLocation>
                  <StartDate>2003-10-27</StartDate>
                  <Address>
                     <CountryCode>1101</CountryCode>
                     <Line1>12 Aden Street</Line1>
                     <Postcode>4444</Postcode>
                     <StateCode>04</StateCode>
                     <Suburb>PT ADELAIDE</Suburb>
                  </Address>
               </OrganisationLocation>
            </Locations>
            <ResponsibleLegalPersons>
               <ResponsibleLegalPerson>
                  <StartDate>2003-10-27</StartDate>
                  <Abns xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                     <a:string>58209574933</a:string>
                  </Abns>
                  <Name>ATEX INC</Name>
               </ResponsibleLegalPerson>
            </ResponsibleLegalPersons>
            <TradingNames>
               <TradingName>
                  <StartDate>2011-09-23</StartDate>
                  <Name>ATEX</Name>
               </TradingName>
            </TradingNames>
            <UpdatedDate xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System">
               <a:DateTime>2012-08-02T02:42:29.1278397Z</a:DateTime>
               <a:OffsetMinutes>600</a:OffsetMinutes>
            </UpdatedDate>
            <Urls>
               <Url>
                  <StartDate>2011-09-23</StartDate>
                  <Link>http://www.atex.au</Link>
               </Url>
            </Urls>
            <Scopes>
               <Scope>
                  <EndDate>2013-10-27</EndDate>
                  <StartDate>2008-10-27</StartDate>
                  <ExtentCode>01</ExtentCode>
                  <IsImplicit>true</IsImplicit>
                  <IsRefused>false</IsRefused>
                  <NrtCode>XXWWRR43</NrtCode>
                  <TrainingComponentType>Unit</TrainingComponentType>
               </Scope>
                ...
            </Scopes>
        </GetDetailsResult>
      </GetDetailsResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I parse the above with:

```
<cfset var stResponse = xmlParse(sResponse)>
```

How would I access the `<Scopes>` nodes,

e.g. with something like:

```
<cfset var res = XMLSearch(stResponse, '//s:Envelope/s:Body/.../Scopes/')>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ColdFusion XmlSearch(): XPath with namespaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005681/coldfusion-xmlsearch-xpath-with-namespaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit that I am not very proficient with ColdFusion, so this may not be the best way to handle the xml, but it works.

```
<cfset stResponse = xmlParse(sResponse)>
<cfset res = stResponse['s:Envelope']['s:Body'].GetDetailsResponse.GetDetailsResult.Scopes>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(res)#" index="i">
    <cfset row = xmlparse(res[i])>
    <strong>Start Date: #row.Scopes.Scope.StartDate.xmltext#</strong>
</cfloop>
```

Replace EndDate with StartDate, ExtentCode, etc. to pull the value.

Comment: Thanks, with some tweaks, I was able to get this concept working:-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//s:Envelope/s:Body/*:GetDetailsResponse/*:GetDetailsResult/*:Scopes/*:Scope/
```

Also read the link posted by @JasonDean, it explains the issue with the namespaces.