# Recursive Query of XML in ColdFusion 8 to find unknown number of children sub levels

Tags: xml, recursion, coldfusion-8

We have a clustered ColdFusion 8 environment consisting of two boxes.  I am trying to traverse XML that was created by Cognos 10.1 to find every element in the order they appear in the XML.  The purpose is to create a thumbnail html representation of the report's unique layout that substitutes icons for elements.

The wrinkle is that Cognos puts a new [block].[content] element for each new object in a report and then nests them based on a layered order determined when the report is created.

For example if you put in a list object with a single column the app will have to traverse through

```
html.body.report.layouts.layout.reportPages.page [...]
pageBody
        block
            contents
                    block=list
                    block
                         contents=column
```

Each report will have a undetermined amount of complexity.  I have parsed the xml using Ben Nadel's techniques for CF8 with cfgroovy and have usable xml source.

Now I have to find if a "list" exists and the order it is in the file.

So far, I've used loops in loops like:

```
<cfset cleanedXml = xmlParse( xhtml ) />
<cfloop array="#XmlSearch(cleanedXml.html.body.report.layouts.layout.reportPages.page,'./.')#"  index="i">
    <cfoutput>
        <cfif structKeyExists(i, "xmlattributes")>
            <cfloop collection="#i.xmlattributes#" item="a">
                #a#: #i.xmlAttributes[a]#<br/>
            </cfloop>
        </cfif>
        <cfloop array="#i.xmlchildren#" index="x">
        #x.xmlName#: #x.xmlText#<br/>

            <cfif structKeyExists(x, "xmlchildren") >
                <cfloop array="#x.xmlchildren#" index="z">
                #z.xmlName#: #z.xmlText#<br/>
                </cfloop>
            </cfif>

        </cfloop>
    </cfoutput>
    <br/>
</cfloop>
```

However, that only goes down two levels (because its only two loops).

I've also tried Recusion with Ben's:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1069-ask-ben-simple-recursion-example.htm

That failed because CF8 does not like having the parent node passed in dynamically.

`cleanedXml.html.body.report.layouts.layout.reportPages.page` works and `cleanedXml.html.body.report.layouts.layout.reportPages.page.#parentString#` does not

It seems like this should be a simple fix, but I just can't get past having to have a loop or recursion for each potential level, which would only break the first time someone wrote a report with one more level than I've anticipated.

If this can't be done in cfml; I am willing try it in jQuery but I would be starting all over again as my jQuery is limited.

Here is a small sample of a 1400 line xml which is a small report file.
Notice the "list" on line 195 then its "listColumn" on line 226, I would need both of these in this order.

```
`
xmlresults - array - Top 1 of 1 rows

1) [xml element]
XmlName:    pageBody 
XmlNsPrefix:     
XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
XmlText:     
XmlComment:  
XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
XmlChildren: 
        [xml element]
        XmlName:    style 
        XmlNsPrefix:     
        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
        XmlText:     
        XmlComment:  
        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
        XmlChildren:

        [xml element]
        XmlName:    contents 
        XmlNsPrefix:     
        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
        XmlText:     
        XmlComment:  
        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
        XmlChildren: 
                [xml element]
                XmlName:    block 
                XmlNsPrefix:     
                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                XmlText:     
                XmlComment:  
                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                XmlChildren: 
                        [xml element]
                        XmlName:    contents 
                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                        XmlText:     
                        XmlComment:  
                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                        XmlChildren: 
                                [xml element]
                                XmlName:    promptButton 
                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                XmlText:     
                                XmlComment:  
                                XmlAttributes:  [struct]
                                        type: back 
                                XmlChildren: 
                                        [xml element]
                                        XmlName:    contents 
                                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                        XmlText:     
                                        XmlComment:  
                                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                        XmlChildren:

                                        [xml element]
                                        XmlName:    style 
                                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                        XmlText:    


                                        XmlComment:  
                                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                        XmlChildren:

                                [xml element]
                                XmlName:    HTMLItem 
                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                XmlText:     
                                XmlComment:  
                                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                XmlChildren: 
                                        [xml element]
                                        XmlName:    dataSource 
                                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                        XmlText:     
                                        XmlComment:  
                                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                        XmlChildren: 
                                                [xml element]
                                                XmlName:    staticValue 
                                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                                XmlText:    

                                                XmlComment:  
                                                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                                XmlChildren:

                                [xml element]
                                XmlName:    textItem 
                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                XmlText:     
                                XmlComment:  
                                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                XmlChildren: 
                                        [xml element]
                                        XmlName:    dataSource 
                                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                        XmlText:     
                                        XmlComment:  
                                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                        XmlChildren: 
                                                [xml element]
                                                XmlName:    staticValue 
                                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                                XmlText:    Note: Clicking the "Back" button will not clear any selected Filters. 
                                                XmlComment:  
                                                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                                XmlChildren:

                        [xml element]
                        XmlName:    style 
                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                        XmlText:     
                        XmlComment:  
                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                        XmlChildren:

                        [xml element]
                        XmlName:    conditionalStyles 
                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                        XmlText:     
                        XmlComment:  
                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                        XmlChildren: 
                                [xml element]
                                XmlName:    conditionalStyleCases 
                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                XmlText:     
                                XmlComment:  
                                XmlAttributes:  [struct]
                                        refvariable: back1 
                                XmlChildren: 
                                        [xml element]
                                        XmlName:    conditionalStyle 
                                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                        XmlText:     
                                        XmlComment:  
                                        XmlAttributes:  [struct]
                                                refvariablevalue: 1 
                                        XmlChildren: 
                                                [xml element]
                                                XmlName:    CSS 
                                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                                XmlText:     
                                                XmlComment:  
                                                XmlAttributes:  [struct]
                                                        value: visibility:hidden 
                                                XmlChildren:

                                [xml element]
                                XmlName:    conditionalStyleDefault 
                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                XmlText:     
                                XmlComment:  
                                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                XmlChildren:

                [xml element]
                XmlName:    block 
                XmlNsPrefix:     
                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                XmlText:     
                XmlComment:  
                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                XmlChildren: 
                        [xml element]
                        XmlName:    contents 
                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                        XmlText:     
                        XmlComment:  
                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                        XmlChildren: 
                                [xml element]
                                XmlName:    list 
                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                XmlText:     
                                XmlComment:  
                                XmlAttributes:  [struct]
                                        horizontalpagination: true
                                        name: List1
                                        refquery: Query1 
                                XmlChildren: 
                                        [xml element]
                                        XmlName:    style 
                                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                        XmlText:    



                                        XmlComment:  
                                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                        XmlChildren:

                                        [xml element]
                                        XmlName:    listColumns 
                                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                        XmlText:     
                                        XmlComment:  
                                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                        XmlChildren: 
                                                [xml element]
                                                XmlName:    listColumn 
                                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                                XmlText:     
                                                XmlComment:  
                                                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                                XmlChildren: 
                                                        [xml element]
                                                        XmlName:    listColumnTitle 
                                                        XmlNsPrefix:     
                                                        XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                                        XmlText:     
                                                        XmlComment:  
                                                        XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                                        XmlChildren: 
                                                                [xml element]
                                                                XmlName:    style 
                                                                XmlNsPrefix:     
                                                                XmlNsURI:   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml 
                                                                XmlText:    


                                                                XmlComment:  
                                                                XmlAttributes:  [struct] 
                                                                XmlChildren:
                                                         `
```

Comment: The results should be testable like this psuedo code:   `Next element? - Do you have children? -yes {loop over children} -no is there a 'list' object? -yes {go get list sub and put in fakie html thumb} -no {next parent}`

Comment: Can you post the actual XML in instead of the dumped representation of it.  If I have time I may try to write something.   You should show us your recursion code.  Chances are, it's just something simple like syntax that's hanging you up. For starters, dynamically addressing struct keys looks like this: myStruct[ keyname ]

Comment: I can't dump the exact xml as they are internal reports; but I'll see about getting a dummy one.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a complete dummy on this one!  I found a answer to my need; not necessarily my question.  Rather than use recusion; I re-looked at my XmlSearch code which I didn't mention because I thought I already ruled it out as a possibility.  Turns out I was just using the wrong syntax!  After finding: [ColdFusion XmlSearch(): XPath with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005681/coldfusion-xmlsearch-xpath-with-namespaces) on stackoverflow I went to these-

http://www.coldfusionguy.com/ColdFusion/blog/index.cfm/2008/9/26/XMLSearch-Specify-xmlns-namespaces-in-an-xPath-Search

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/827-nylon-technology-presentation-introduction-to-xpath-and-xmlsearch-in-coldfusion.htm

Which led to:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

I've created a search that will display the results in the order they appear in in the xml!

```
`<cfset listInXml = #XmlSearch(cleanedXml,"//*[ local-name()='list' or local-name()='combinationChart' ]")# >`
```

This returned Chart, Chart, List, Chart... etc. like it is in my jsfiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/asheppardwork/3uuaj5jb/1/

I got stuck because I was only using the syntax that Ben Nadel had on his site; I never figured it might have changed since then for cf8.

I hope this helps anyone else looking for the same type of thing.